# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module, components not found

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i have an issue with vue in laravel , when i upload the project on server gettings the below error on local everythings working fine !

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './components/ProfileSkillComponent.vue'
    at webpackMissingModule (app.js:334098:133)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:334098:246)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20:30)
    at Object.0 (app.js:348515:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20:30)
    at app.js:84:18
    at app.js:87:10
```

Comment: Generally devs use version control for getting code onto the server such as git rather than raw uploading. You might have failed to upload all changed and/or new files.

Comment: @KevinY i have repositry on github with project i clone it directly on server then i installed npm and composer same repo working perfectly on local and not on life sever.

Comment: You should try isolating the problem to get a better sense of what/where the problem is and what/where the problem isn't. Might try setting it up locally a second time using another git clone etc and see if you run into the same issue. Might try similar on the server in a new directory to see if a fresh install has any difference. You might have some stuff git ignored or didn't do an `npm run production` etc on your local before committing etc. Just be cautious not to destroy what's currently working locally without a way to get it working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was case sensitive as i have uploaded project on Cento OS and  i was working on Win OS seems wired but i changed from Cap to small letters and everything worked proper